# How to understand what PCIe 3.0 vs 5.0 is on motherboard specs?

Tags: pci-express

The latest motherboards that have been released seem to advertise PCIe 3.0 support, but the latest PCIe spec is 5.0 with 6.0 on the way.

Are these latest motherboards really pinned to PCIe version 3.0, or are they complying with 5.0, but just advertising 3.0 as some sort of marketing anomaly?

If they are really pinned to 3.0, why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Specs being agreed on and then those specs being placed into production are two different things.

#### Yes, the final [PCI Express 5.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#PCI_Express_5.0) specs was introduced in May 2019 but the [PCI Express 6.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#PCI_Express_6.0) specs are still in process with the last update being November 2020.

Specifications are just mutually agreed upon ways of handling and doing things: These are the pinouts, this I the data spec, here are the power requirements and here is the acceptable boundaries of this specification.

But a specification is not the final step. The next step is to get manufacturers onboard with the spec an gear them up for manufacturing. As of the time of this post, only first demo systems of PCIe 5.0 are being unveiled and introduced to the world. But this is — again — one of the first steps of the process. As e[xplained in this ExtremeTech article from October 2020](https://www.extremetech.com/computing/316257-intel-demos-pcie-5-0-on-upcoming-sapphire-rapids-cpus) discussing a recent demo system using PCIe 5.0:

> “The goal of this type of testing is to demonstrate Intel’s commitment to future high-speed interfaces, as well as to create reference platforms for early PCIe 5.0 certification.”
>
> “It’s also a sign that PCIe 5.0 could show up on motherboards in as little as 12 months, though I think 2022 is a bit more likely than late 2021. If Intel launches Rocket Lake at the end of Q1 2021, as is expected, it’s not clear the company would then refresh Alder Lake in the October / November time frame. Typically Intel likes to wait a bit longer than that between product cycles.”

Why does it take so long? Easy: Manufacturing of new chips and related hardware to support new specs is not an overnight thing. It takes time to develop all of that to make it a practical reality.

Also, gearing up to do something like that too soon might be a gamble: What if nobody cares about new PCIe specs to this degree? What if people are perfectly fine with PCIe 3.0? And what do you do with the tons of PCIe 3.0 hardware out there?

Remember, hardware manufacturing is a business: Why would a company sit on already manufactured PCIe 3.0 hardware just to rush PCIe 5.0 and — eventually — PCIe 6.0 systems into existence? What financial gain do they get by doing that?

So while new specs always seem cool, they typically do not show up right away after a set of specs is standardized.